# Is there any tradition of anagogical interpretation in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, interpretation, exegesis, hermeneutics

The word “anagogical” is used by Christians to describe [one of the four senses of interpreting biblical scripture, historical, allegorical, moral, and anagogical.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-is-the-fourfold-sense-of-scripture/38888#38888) The anagogical sense was about interpreting scripture in light of humanity’s eternal destiny.
Did Hinduism ever developing something similar to anagogical interpretation when interpreting Hindu scripture?